# Кэшированный роутинг | JS | Service Worker

Tags: javascript, react-router, service-worker

Начал разбраться, как работает service worker и столкнулся с проблемой. У меня на странице есть роутинг (react-router), и если смотреть через вкладку network, то каждый роут он воспринимает как отдельную страницу.
Как мне правильно закэшировать все это? Нет смысла кэшировать конкретные роуты, т.к. что `domain/`, что `domain/hash/id` имеют один и тот же html код.

Пробовал как описано выше, но это работает через раз, а иногда страница просто начинает бесконечно перезагружаться. Как правильно кэшировать такие данные, чтобы я мог пользоваться роутингом даже при отключенном интернете?

ServiceWorker.js

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
const {url} = e.request;

if (url.startsWith('http')) {
    e.respondWith(respondNetworkFirstWithSavedToCache(e));
    return true;
}

return false;
});
```

respondNetworkFirstWithSavedToCache

```
async function respondNetworkFirstWithSavedToCache(e) {
    try {
        const { url, method } = e.request;
        const pathname = new URL(url).pathname;
        const remote = await fetch(e.request);

        if (!remote?.ok) {
            return respondWithCache(e);
        }

        const canCached = isPage(e);
        if (canCached) {
            const toCache = remote.clone();
            self.caches.open(ASSET_CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
                try {
                    return cache?.put(e.request, toCache);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    
                }
            });
        }

        return remote;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return respondWithCache(e, false);
    }
}
async function respondWithCache(e, fetched = true) {
    const cacheResult = await withTimeout(async () => {
        const cache = await self.caches.open(ASSET_CACHE_NAME);
        if (isPage(e)) {
            const requestToPage = await findCachedPage(cache);
            if (requestToPage) {
                const cached = await cache.match(requestToPage);
                return {cache, cached};
            }
        }

        const cached = await cache.match(e.request);

        return {cache, cached};
    }, TIMEOUT);

    const {cache, cached} = cacheResult || {};

    if (cache && cached) {
    if (cached.ok) {
        return cached;
    } else {
        await cache.delete(e.request);
    }
}

if (!fetched) return false;
const remote = await fetch(e.request);

if (remote.ok && cache) {
    cache.put(e.request, remote.clone());
}

return remote;
}

function isPage(e) {
   return e.request.destination === "document";
}

async function findCachedPage(cache) {
    const requests = await cache.keys();
    return (requests ?? []).find(e => { //Исключаю кэшированные GET запросы и запросы на ассеты (медиа/стили/скрипты и т.п.)
        const {url, method} = e;
        const pathname = new URL(url).pathname;
        const isServiceRequest = isAssets(url) || url.match(RE_CACHE_FIRST_ASSETS) || url.match(FROM_STATIC_DIR);
        const isCachedResponse = method === "GET" && CACHED_FETCHES.includes(pathname);
        return !isServiceRequest && !isCachedResponse;
    });
}
```